# I have a camera outputting RGB565 format but colours are all wrong

Tags: image, rgb, image-formats

I have a small CMOS sensor (OV7670) which outputs raw pixel data in the RGB565 format. If I view an image I can make it out but the colours are wrong and I am not sure why.

The raw file is [here](https://www.NoFile.io/f/xION8QMMH4J).

This is what the raw file looks like when I view it on [RawPixels Online Viewer](http://rawpixels.net/)

[image: This is what the image looks like]

and the image below is what it should look like

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no bytes with the top bit set in that file, but there should have been. Is D[7] connected properly?

Comment: Hi. Can you explain a bit more please. All lines look to be correct;y connected. If D[7] wasnt connected wouldnt I just get a black pixels for that bit? What shoudl I expect for the top bit and maybe I can double check further. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Your raw file is corrupt. Send exact image. It doesn't look like it's R565. Everything about it wrong.

- You didn't even say what dimensions. File size is 800001, this cannot be, as sizes should be even.
- Since it's solid color blocks R565 would look like representative
  pairs of bytes. In you raw image it doesn't look like it at all: `{ef 9f 87, ef 9f 87, ...}` This is supposed to be the first stripe and it cannot be white.
- At the bottom of the image are only NULLs, sample wasn't taken properly.
- It looks like line size of the buffer is 1280 bytes. E.g. it could be
  640 pixels wide if it were r565 and 625 pixes in height. With that I
  do not get anything as you show.

If I look at it as 640x625 R565 I get this:

[image]

Comment: The size of the image is VGA 640x480. The nulls at the end are because I have a wide buffer for greater resolutions. I just need to strip the nulls but the result is the same. Thank you for your reply. What area do I need to look at.

Comment: the first bytes should be white so what should I expect the first bytes to look like. thanks.

Comment: Just noticed that the image you posted is with the little endian bit set. If you disable that it will look like the image posted.

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin white would look more like FF FF FF FF or something close to that.

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin Yes, I know, I used ffmpeg to convert, it does little endian r565